# Anything comparable to Visual Basic to use in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rad

Is there anything comparable to Visual Basic to use in Ubuntu?

Comment: Visual Basic or Visual Studio?

Comment: Is it the equivalent of Windows Forms designer that you would like to use in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 14):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Visual_Basic) supports VB.NET.

Comment: +1: Although Mono is typically a little behind feature-wise, it's a great alternative in linux.

Answer (score 5):

[Python](http://www.python.org/) perhaps?

> Python is a programming language that
>   lets you work more quickly and
>   integrate your systems more
>   effectively. You can learn to use
>   Python and see almost immediate gains
>   in productivity and lower maintenance
>   costs.

Also, perhaps [KBasic](http://freshmeat.net/projects/kbasic/) would be of interest.

> KBasic is a programming language
>   related to VB.NET, Visual Basic,
>   Visual Basic for Applications, and
>   Java. It combines the best features of
>   those tools and comes with built-in
>   backward-compatibility support for VB,
>   VBA, and QBasic. It also comes with
>   support for VB.NET syntax, functions,
>   and similar objects and classes. It
>   allows developers with an installed
>   base of VB applications to start
>   developing for a mixed-platform
>   environment. KBasic comprises a
>   compiler, an interpreter, and an
>   integrated development environment.

Comment: I gut feeling makes me believe that he reffers to an alternative for Visual Studio, not Visual Basic.

Answer (score 5):

Mono for VB.NET

```
sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc monodevelop
```

[Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html) is similar to VB 6.0

```
sudo apt-get install gambas2
```

Answer (score 4):

Kylix, now as Lazarus, if you aren't tied to a Basic variant (its Pascal based)

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it but you might consider [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Visual_Basic) although I am not sure if it will work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Python but DOSEMU+QBasic works as well :-)

Comment: For the guys above: I meant Visual Basic. dmityogov, I appreciate the tip on DOSEMU. I still use DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Use [Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net). It is a [RAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) application with complete IDE integration, thanks to Benoit.

Much sample code is also available from the web. Go to **Synaptic Package Manager**, search for **Gambas2** and then click apply. It'll automatically add dependencies.

[image: Click gambas2, it'll automatically add dependencies.]

Answer (score 0):

There is Theseus for [bigFORTH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigforth/). See also [this page](http://www.jwdt.com/~paysan/bigforth.html#MINOS) - it generates object oriented Forth code.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I guess I’ll have to start trying your suggestions to see what comes closest to VB—or pehaps better.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [KBasic](http://kbasic.com/). It has everything you would be looking for in VB.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby

A vastly better language than VB is Ruby.

Other alternatives are awk, Perl, and Python. Even the shell is good for small programs.